# Javascript file being called in an html file on

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, input

I have code that has a ball bouncing around on a canvas I create hte canvas in HTML and the ball code is in a .js file. When I run the html file the ball code does not work but when I put the ball code between  tags in the html file it does work. Anyone see what reason it doesn't work whe its in a .js file?

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html> 
    <header> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <title>Bouncing Ball Paint</title> 
        <body>
            Welcome to Paint Brush! 
            Before you begin: Please type in a color, width, and speed. Now sit back and enjoy the show.</body>
        <body>
        <style> 
        #ball{background:#CCC;} 
        </style> 
    </header> 
    <body style="background-color:#FFDEAD;"> 
        Ball Width: <input type="text" id="lineWidth"></input> 
        Ball Color: <input type="text" id="lineColor"></input> 
        Ball Speed X:<input type="text" id="speedx"></input> 
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href"> 
        <input type="button" value="Green" id="green" onclick= "DGN.GreenRect()" />
        <div id="container"> 


        <canvas id="ball" width="1000" height="700"></canvas> 

        <script type="text/javascript" 

        src="balledit3.js"> </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code I'm trying to have in a .js file but will work between  tags in html:

```
var x=50; 
var y=300; 
var dx=10; 
var dy=10; 

function draw(){ 
    var canvas = document.getElementById('ball'); 
    context= ball.getContext('2d'); 
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
    lineColor = (document.getElementById('lineColor').value.length>0)?document.getElementById('lineColor').value:'#0000FF'; 
    lineWidth = (document.getElementById('lineWidth').value.length>0)?document.getElementById('lineWidth').value:'10'; 
    context.beginPath(); 
    context.fillStyle=lineColor; 
    context.arc(x,y,lineWidth,20,Math.PI*2,true); 
    context.closePath(); 
    if (lineWidth){ 
        context.lineWidth=lineWidth; 
    } 
    if (lineColor){ 
        context.strokeStyle=lineColor; 
        context.stroke(); 
    } 
    context.fill(); 
    if( x<0 || x>1000) 
    dx=-dx; 
    if( y<0 || y>700) 
    dy=-dy; 
    x+=dx; 
    y+=dy; 
    fr = (document.getElementById('speedx').value>0)?document.getElementById('speedx').value:50; 
    setTimeout(draw,fr);   
} 
draw();
```

Comment: There are some serious issues with your HTML code.  Consider [validating your code](http://validator.w3.org) to see if it corrects your problem.

Comment: If not - what kind of error do you get if you check the javascript error console?

Comment: There are two extra body tags, one with text and one that is unclosed, in the header that should not be there. An HTML document only gets one header, and one body.

Comment: it's not a header tag but a `<head>` tag

Comment: Indeed, you don't get to see the header in the markup...

Comment: You have 2 `body` tags, `header` is not supposed where it appears in the markup. I strongly suggest you follow MrSlayers advice and check if the problems still persist if your markup is valid. I checked the JavaScript - no complaints about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your HTML and it seems to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bouncing Ball Paint</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>#ball{background:#CCC;}</style> 
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#FFDEAD;">
        <p>Welcome to Paint Brush!</p>
        <p>Before you begin: Please type in a color, width, and speed. Now sit back and enjoy the show.</p>
        <form id="container">
            <fieldset>
                <label>Ball Width:</label><input type="text" id="lineWidth" />
                <br />
                <label>Ball Color:</label><input type="text" id="lineColor" />
                <br />
                <label>Ball Speed X:<input type="text" id="speedx" />
            </fieldset>
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
            <input type="button" value="Green" id="green" onclick="javascript:DGN.GreenRect();" />
            <fieldset>
                <canvas id="ball" width="1000" height="700">This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.</canvas>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="draw.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Got it thank You. You defnitely cleaned the HTML and altered the look of it a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone I appreciate input as well when I' not coding correctly as well. Thanks!